# How to get case-sensitivity in Section names?

Tags: python, case-sensitive, configparser

I've got an win32 app accessed by users via RDP acess.
Each user has his/her own `user_app.ini` file.

When I upgrade my app on the RDP server, I sometimes need to create/modify entries in the `user_app.ini` file of each user. I wrote a Python script to handle the job that use some `upgrade.ini` file to update all the `user_app.ini` files, using the `ConfigParser` module.

My problem is that my section names should be seen as case insensitive, but `ConfigParser` is case-sensitive regarding *sections* (while it can be case insensitve regarding *options* using  `optionxform()` )

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an [`SECTCRE`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html#configparser.SECTCRE) attribute that you can override. This should define a regular expression that will match the section name.

Instead of a regex you can pass any object that has a `match` method which takes a string and returns an object which has a `group` method that accepts the string `'header'` as parameter.

For example:

```
class FakeRe:
    def __init__(self, regex):
        self.regex = regex
    def match(self, text):
        m = self.regex.match(text)
        if m:
            return FakeMatch(m)
        return None

class FakeMatch:
    def __init__(self, match):
        self.match = match
    def group(self, name):
        return self.match.group(name).lower()
```

You could then set that attribute when creating a parser:

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.SECTCRE = FakeRe(re.compile(r'\[\s*(?P<header>some regex here)\s*\]')
```

and this parser should consider all section names as lower-case.

You may have to tweak the code a bit, depending on your exact needs.